# Deleting sidebar from head and reset with only master remaining

Tags: git, git-branch

[image: a problem Im having]

How do I change the head to only master while deleting the sidebar and reset parts and tag in git>? Ive tried everything to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the local `sidebar` & `reset` branch.

```
$ git branch -D sidebar  # delete local 'sidebar' branch
$ git branch -D reset    # delete local 'reset' branch

$ git log --oneline --decorate
```

If you want to give a tag (say, v1.0.0) on the latest commit of `HEAD`.

```
$ git tag -a v1.0.0 -m "message"
```

If you have any `tag` on the commit and want to delete it:

```
$ git tag -d <tag-name>  # delete a tag
```

Answer (score 0):

It's now at detached HEAD, most probably caused by `git checkout 36c8f23`.

Now run `git checkout master` and `HEAD` will be point at `master`.

If you want to delete the branches `sidebar` and `reset`, run `git branch -d sidebar reset`.

If you want to delete the tag `v1.0`, run `git tag -d v1.0`.

Comment: Thanks alot I spent 2 hours trying to figure it out